# Commerce RRP translation

Tags: commerce, i18n-l10n

The special price attributes provided by [Commerce Exra Price Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_price_formatters) are not translatable. Especially RRP. I cannot change the translations of these fields. I can write the label in the display dialog but it is not changeable depending on the site's language. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bugs like this, it's best to do a quick search of the module's issue queue. There are two issues, one with a patch that appears to do the job!

https://www.drupal.org/node/1804142